# Is there a way to get the throughput or latency of a WebRTC stream from a RTCPeerConnection?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I want to calculate either the latency or throughput of a receiving stream for WebRTC. I know there is the `getStats()` but I can't seem to find an easy way of doing it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/ gives an example of how to use the getStats API to measure the bitrate of a video stream. The general pattern is to call getStats twice in a time interval and divide the difference in the counts by the time difference.

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/ shows a more complete list of what statistics are available.

Comment: While I understand where you're coming from, answers in StackOverflow can not rely **only** on outsourced information.  "The general pattern..." sentence seems a bit small when OP said they knew about this method already. Maybe you could include a simplified version of the code from [l247](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/js/main.js#L247) to [l261](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/js/main.js#L261)  for instance?

Comment: you're suggesting stackoverflow answers are a better venue than a github repository with more than 6k stars?

Comment: No, I'm just stating that stackoverflow answers should be self-contained. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer